# MySQL query works fine on db client but PHP gives SQLSTATE[42000] error

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have kind of weird situation. Long story short, I have a MySQL query and when PHP runs it, it gives

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ' ' at line 6.

However, when I run it on db client applications like DataGrip or SequelPro - it works fine and returns the set of rows.

```
echo $sQuery; // I print the query right before the execution
$stmt = $dbh->prepare ($sQuery);
$stmt->execute(); // This is the line that gives the error
$rResult = $stmt->fetchAll();
unset ($stmt);
```

So, have any of you got this kind of weird problem before and what will be the best approach in order to solve this issue?

QUERY:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS max(r.id) AS id
    ,r.client_name AS client_name
    ,r.ban_no AS ban_no
    ,r.ban_type
    ,(
        CASE 
            WHEN c.total_subscribers IS NOT NULL
                THEN c.total_subscribers
            ELSE r.subscribers
            END
        ) AS subscribers
    ,r.deal_value
    ,(
        CASE 
            WHEN c.potential_renewals IS NOT NULL
                THEN c.potential_renewals
            ELSE r.potential_renewals
            END
        ) AS potential_renewals
    ,r.prev_sales_rep_id
    ,r.sales_rep_id
    ,r.city
    ,ce.postal_code AS postal_code
    ,r.outlet_id
    ,(
        CASE 
            WHEN (
                    IFNULL(r.activity_type, 0) != '0'
                    AND IFNULL(r.activity_type, 0) != '4'
                    AND IFNULL(r.activity_type, 0) != '5'
                    AND (r.last_spoken IS NOT NULL)
                    AND (to_days(r.last_spoken) + 15 > to_days(r.call_date))
                    )
                THEN 'Yes'
            ELSE 'No'
            END
        ) AS activity_type
    ,r.ban_type AS STATUS
FROM TableR r
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ban_id
        ,type
        ,date_added
        ,COALESCE(total_subscribers, 0) AS total_subscribers
        ,COALESCE(potential_renewals, 0) AS potential_renewals
    FROM TableCS cs1
    WHERE cs1.ban_id IN (
            '6375305622668619'
            ,'7852790096027066'
            )
    GROUP BY cs1.ban_id
    ) c ON r.ban_no = c.ban_id
LEFT JOIN TableCE ce ON r.ban_no = ce.ban_no
WHERE (r.ban_type != 'D')
    AND r.dealer_id = '15'
GROUP BY r.ban_no
ORDER BY `subscribers` DESC LIMIT 0
    ,50;
```

Comment: What's your query?

Comment: sounds like a quoting issue to me and/or empty value, but we won't know that till we see full code

Comment: since you either left the question or are trying to fix it yourself, nobody can answer this. I myself have left the question. Good luck.

Comment: @Fred-ii- its okay. Thanks so much.

Comment: The thing is if there will be problem on query it should not work fine on db client apps as well. So thats why I have not include my query in here. 
Just would like to know if someone has the same kind of problem before.

Comment: Sure, lots of people. But without the query, we can't point you in the right direction.

Comment: @aynber Sure, if you think it might be helpful. I just add it to the question body. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Okay so,

I could not figured out the reason but however,

```
$list_of_bansas_string .= '\''.$call_list_record[0].'\','; // we used single quote to solve the problem
```

It was the first reason. So its secure to use single quote instead of double.

```
$list_of_bansas_string[strlen($list_of_bansas_string)-1] = '  '; // we can't assign empty string, we should put space on it
```

Literally, PHP does not allow me to assign empty char. So, I ended up to replace with space character and it worked.

Comment: Basically you were using prepared statements without binding any parameters and providing user input manually.